# Automatic upgrade/update of .NET and Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

With the upcoming release of .NET 4 in mind, what are the reasons that Microsoft doesn't automatically update and upgrade the .NET Platform on all installed Windows System? Is it a legal issue?

Even Windows 7 doesn't ship with Silverlight on board and it hurts my heart everytime a customers doesn't want to install a new release of my software on his/her system because even a .NET Update takes ages to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Microsoft doesn't want to break existing applications. That's why IE6 was never upgraded in the service packs for Windows XP.

Shipping Silverlight with Windows would result in yet another lawsuit because it 'hurts' the competition/Adobe.